# Slack API Channel name to conversation id

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have an old slack app that relies on [channel.join](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.join). I need to migrate [conversations.join](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.join). The APIs have two different keys. Channels allows you to use the channel name, and conversations requires a conversation id. How do you convert them? conversations.list -> loop?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to loop. The new API is very focused on IDs and the advice is to store the IDs of the channels you want to join not their names, because name can be changed at any time. It feels like they’re saying you can join by name if you want but we won’t make it easy for you :) It's probably good advice tbh.